# C# passing multiple oracle PL\SQL blocks gets "Encountered the symbol / "

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to pass the oracle a PL\SQL script consists of a multiple blocks (begin/end).
The following example code works on SqlDev, but not with C#.

```
BEGIN 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE()) || ' Block1');
END;
/

BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE()) || ' Block2');
END;
```

C# code:

```
var str = @"
begin 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE()) || ' Block1'); 
end;
/
begin 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE()) || ' Block2');
end;
";
str = str.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n");
ExecuteNonQueryThis(str2)
```

The error I get:

```
ORA-06550: line 5, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/"
```

Is it even possible to execute a multi-block-script of Oracle via the C#?

Comment: The process is right

Just Remove '/'and execute.

Comment: I suspect you should also remove the line `str = str.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\n");`. PL/SQL doesn't know anything about C-style character escape sequences such as `\n`. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

just wrap it into one begin end

```
var str = @"
begin

begin 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE()) || ' Block1'); 
end;

begin 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE()) || ' Block2');
end;

end;";
```